# save() command in matlab engine for python

Tags: python, matlab, workspace, mat-file, matlab-engine

I am using MATLAB Engine API for Python
https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

I would like to open and save a file.

```
#import and start the engine
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
print('Matlab engine started')
#File of interest
myBadFile='test.mat'
#Synchronize python/matlab working directory
eng.cd(os.getcwd(),nargout=0)
print(eng.pwd())
#Read file contents
VALUES=eng.load(myBadFile,nargout=1)
```

So far so good. I am actually surprised it worked so smoothly.

I do my stuff on `VALUES`, then I would like to save it again.
If I do

> ```
> VALUES=eng.save(myBadFile+'.test','VALUES','-v6',nargout=0)
> ```

I get:

```
MatlabExecutionError: Variable 'VALUES' not found.
```

If I do

```
VALUES=eng.save(myBadFile+'.test',VALUES,'-v6',nargout=0)
```

I get

```
MatlabExecutionError: Argument must contain a character vector.
```

So how do I save my VALUES which is a valid variable in python environment but it is not seen in matlab apparently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) operates on the variables contained in MATLAB's workspace, and Python does not share scope with the MATLAB engine instance(s). The [`matlab.engine`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.engine.matlabengine-class.html) instance, however, does have a [`workspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.engine.matlabengine-class.html#bukig7r-9) attribute, defined as follows:

> Python dictionary containing references to MATLAB variables. You can
>   assign data to, and get data from, a MATLAB variable through the
>   `workspace`. The name of each MATLAB variable you create becomes a key
>   in the `workspace` dictionary. The keys in `workspace` must be valid
>   MATLAB identifiers (for example, you cannot use numbers as keys).

Which you can use to place variables in MATLAB's scope.

This code, for example:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
x = [1, 2, 3]
eng.save('test.mat', 'x')
```

Fails as above:

```
Error using save
Variable 'x' not found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\excaza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matlab\engine\matlabengine.py", line 78, in __call__
    _stderr, feval=True).result()
  File "C:\Users\excaza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matlab\engine\futureresult.py", line 68, in result
    return self.__future.result(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\excaza\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matlab\engine\fevalfuture.py", line 82, in result
    self._result = pythonengine.getFEvalResult(self._future,self._nargout, None, out=self._out, err=self._err)
matlab.engine.MatlabExecutionError: Variable 'x' not found.
```

But works fine once we copy `x` into the `workspace` dict:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
x = [1, 2, 3]
eng.workspace['x'] = x
eng.save('test.mat', 'x')
```